# Running node apps with CodeDeploy

Tags: node.js, aws-code-deploy

I am using Codeship as my CI tool, I integrate it with AWS CodeDeploy service. The procedure is perfect until my appspec.yml file calls my script to run the node app. Even though I have npm, node, bower and grunt installed I get command not found errors.

[image: Errors]

Answer (score 0):

I would try editing your start_server.sh and adding npm and node to the $PATH environment variable or put that path directly in the command itself.

So instead of
     `npm install`

Try
    `/usr/local/bin/npm install`

That might not be where your npm lives but if you need to find out just do `which npm`

Comment: Well that was one of my many attempts to fix the issue. But even with the path I got the same error

Comment: Are you doing the path change in the same start_server.sh script?

Comment: Yes I found the path with 'which' and made the changes in start_server.sh script

Comment: Can you post the whole script?

Comment: Well man sorry then. They only other thing I can think of to check is what user the script is running as and make sure path lines up for that as well.

Comment: I already check that by running the "whoami" command in the script.

Answer (score 0):

Perform the below steps:

1. which node
2. sudo ln -s /home/ubuntu/.nvm/versions/node/v12.13.1/bin/node (output of above step) /usr/bin/node
3. which npm
4. sudo ln -s /home/ubuntu/.nvm/versions/node/v12.13.1/bin/npm (output of above step) /usr/bin/npm

and try to use it via /usr/bin/npm install

I hope this will help you!!

Answer (score 0):

For people who still might run into the same problem.

Check your appspec.yml file and look at the destination, it should contain something like /home/ec2-user....

in this case we need to make sure code deploy agent runs with that user profile (ec2-user). Check this [link](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/codedeploy-agent-non-root-profile/) for steps to to make code deploy to run with your user profile